# How to compile video with variable in vuejs?

Tags: database, vue.js, camera, record

Am using vuejs language ,but i need to make multiple camera to record my garden with variable like temperature ,co2 ,weter in trees ,water tank level ,...
So my problem atr how to make all variable with videos record like database ,and when i will to returni can see by interval time video ,like cctv camera ,with gauges?

How to make video record with data variable ,by using vuejs?

Comment: Vue is not a language and has nothing to do with the task you describe. The language is Javascript and it's unknown in which way it can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So ,it's not have any idea to do thats with javascript and json ,to make video with variables?